# sufficient and necessary conditions for a set to be a convex hull in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-hulls

In this question $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ and by convex hull I mean the smallest (w.r.t. inclusion) convex set $C(A)$ that contains $A$.

Now, let us define:
$$A_k=\{\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_ia_i:\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i=1,\lambda_i\in[0,1],a_i\in A\}$$
It is possible to show that $A_3=C(A)$ for any $A$. It is also obvious that $A=A_1=C(A)$ iff $A$ is convex.

My question is, what are the sufficient and\or necessary conditions for $A_2=C(A)$?

Comment: I would think that your characterization happens iff all points in $A$ lie on a line.

Comment: @max_zorn This isn't true. For example taking two parallel lines of the same length would still have $A_2=C(A)$. Furthermore, I'm confident that if A is path connected then $A_2=C(A)$, but I didn't find a proof for this.

Comment: you are correct. More generally, the union of two convex sets has your property, by Caratheodory.